# Connection reset at read()

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am trying to implement a server and client based on the web socket technologie but when I run the TCPDataServer class I am getting the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: connection reset
at java.io.DataInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.server.ClientWorker.run(TCPDataServer.java:67)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I excepted to get the following output `Hello, I am Alex!`

**TCPDataClient**

```
package org.client;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class TCPDataClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            TCPDataClient obj = new TCPDataClient();
            Socket obj_client = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.1"), 1000);
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(obj_client.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(obj_client.getOutputStream());
            byte[] buffer = obj.createDataPacket("Hello, I am Alex!".getBytes("UTF8"));
            dout.write(buffer);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private byte[] createDataPacket(byte[] data) {

        byte[] packet = null;
        try {
            byte[] initialize = new byte[1];
            initialize[0] = 2;
            byte[] separator = new byte[1];
            separator[0] = 4;
            byte[] data_length = String.valueOf(data.length).getBytes("UIF8");
            packet = new byte[initialize.length + separator.length + data_length.length + data.length];

            System.arraycopy(initialize, 0, packet, 0, initialize.length);
            System.arraycopy(data_length, 0, packet, initialize.length, data_length.length);
            System.arraycopy(separator, 0, packet, initialize.length + data_length.length, separator.length);
            System.arraycopy(data, 0, packet, initialize.length + data_length.length + separator.length, data.length);


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return packet;

    }

}
```

**TCPDataServer**

```
package org.server;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import com.sun.istack.internal.logging.Logger;

public class TCPDataServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            ServerSocket server_socket = new ServerSocket(1000);
            while (true) {
                new Thread(new ClientWorker(server_socket.accept())).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
              System.err.println("Error");
              System.err.println(e);
              System.err.println("\n2");
              System.err.println(e.getMessage());
              System.err.println("\n3");
              System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
              System.err.println("\n4");
              System.err.println(e.getCause());
              System.err.println("\n5");
              System.err.println(Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
              System.err.println("\n6");
              e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

class ClientWorker implements Runnable {
    private Socket target_socket;
    private DataInputStream din;
    private DataOutputStream dout;

    public ClientWorker(Socket recv_scket) {

        try {
            target_socket = recv_scket;
            din = new DataInputStream(target_socket.getInputStream());
            dout = new DataOutputStream(target_socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            byte[] initilize = new byte[1];
            try {
                din.read(initilize, 0, initilize.length);
                if (initilize[0] == 2) {
                    //This is line 67.
                    System.out.println(new String(readStream()));

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private byte[] readStream() {
        byte[] data_buff = null;

        try {
            int b = 0;
            String buff_length = "";
            while ((b = din.read()) != 4) {
                buff_length += (char) b;
            }
            int data_length = Integer.parseInt(buff_length);
            data_buff = new byte[Integer.parseInt(buff_length)];
            int byte_read = 0;
            int byte_offset = 0;
            while (byte_offset < data_length) {
                byte_read = din.read(data_buff, byte_read, data_length - byte_offset);
                byte_offset += byte_read;

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return data_buff;

    }

}
```

Comment: Should it be `127.0.0.1` rather than `127.0.1`?

Comment: yes u are righz I changed it but I am getting now `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.DataInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at org.server.ClientWorker.run(TCPDataServer.java:65)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

Comment: This line in the run() method ... din.read(initilize, 0, initilize.length);

Comment: Another spotted problem is that there is only `UTF-8` no `UIF-8`. Still irrelevant though.

Comment: @PEMapModder:Ich changed it to UTF-8 but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you tried doing a graceful close? (IIRC, have the client call shutdownOutput and then call read until it gets EOF; shutdownOutput will make the server get EOF and the server will close the socket in response to that)

Comment: By the way @PEMapModder, 127.0.1 is a perfectly valid alternative way of writing 127.0.0.1. (Other ways include 127.1 and 2130706433)

Answer (score 0):

In your Server program you have used `din` as your input stream reader which reads from the socket.
In your Client program you have used `dout` as output stream writer which writes to the underlying socket
In your `ClientWorker` class you have given multiple read operations using `din`from the socket, whereas you have given only one write operation to the stream using `dout` object.

The `din` object will be blocking/waiting to receive the data from client side, but unfortunately you would have closed (program ends) your socket connection on your client which is reason for the `DataInputStream` to throw `IOException`.

And your `din` object will throw an IO error if your underlying socket/stream has been close and yet you are trying read using it.

Try to maintain the same number of reads and writes on either side (client/server).

Answer (score -1):

You aren't closing the sockets, so your OS is resetting them when the JVM exits.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer! I have closed the socket like this `   byte[] buffer = obj.createDataPacket("Hello, I am Alex!".getBytes("UTF-8"));
   dout.write(buffer);
   din.close();
   dout.close();
   obj_client.close();` but I am still getting `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) at java.io.DataInputStream.read(Unknown Source) at org.server.ClientWorker.run(TCPDataServer.java:65) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source`